# How much objects can we create in 32-bits systems?

Tags: .net, memory-management, heap-memory

In .NET, to just exist, an object needs 12 bytes, 8 for the header and 4 to be referenced. Suppose that we want to create a maximum number of 12 bytes objects that a 32-bits systems can handle (ignoring the 100% overhead). What this maximum value could be ?
I have read [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/object-overhead-the-hidden-.net-memory--allocation-cost/)
that we can create 170 million object, but as I know, 32 bits systems can manage at max 4 Go of ram, I don't know from where the 170 million object came.

Comment: These numbers are pretty useless, why do you need to know? Perhaps there is a better answer to the underlying question.

Comment: I was trying to figure out what is the best way to decrease the overhead amount. 
Since increasing data bytes means having a class with a lot of fields, which increases complexity of the class, i'm wondering if there is a tolerable amount of overhead, or it depends on the memory management needs ?

Comment: You should most likely not worry about this overhead and instead design classes the way you want to. If you have large-scale data concerns you should likely move to 64-bit anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1,024 MB = 1 GB

2 GB = 2,048 MB
2,048 MB * 1,024 = 2,097,152 KB
2,097,152 KB * 1024 = 2,147,483,648 B

2,147,483,648 B / 12 = 178,956,970 170million (ish)
```

As the article points out, there is some overhead in there, and objects of this size are practically useless.  But anyway, above is the maths for GB -> B / 12 conversion.